# How does this subclass instantiate itself?

Tags: objective-c, super, subclassing

I'm looking at some code from a pod called PKRevealController that appears odd to me. The pod defines a subclass of CABasicAnimation called PKAnimation:

```
@interface PKAnimation : CABasicAnimation <PKAnimating>
```

Then it has a factory method in the implementation:

```
+ (id)animationWithKeyPath:(NSString *)path
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [super animationWithKeyPath:path];
    animation.delegate = animation;
    return animation;
}
```

This function actually returns an instance of PKAnimation. To me it looks like it should return a CABasicAnimation. How is that achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `[super something]`, you are using the superclass's implementation of the method, but the method is still *called on* the same object that the current method is called on. In other words, the `self` in the super call is the same as the `self` in the current function -- the `PKAnimation` class (or whatever class you called this method on).

This depends on knowing that `+[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:]` creates an object of the class that it's called on. But this is a convention that is followed by all convenience constructors in Cocoa. They always create the object using `[self alloc] ...` rather than `[SomeSpecificClass alloc] ...`, therefore, it will always use the class object that the method (which may be inherited) is called on at runtime, not the class that the code is physically in at compile time.

In other words, if `PKAnimation` *didn't* override `+animationWithKeyPath:`, calling `[PKAnimation animationWithKeyPath:...]` will *still* return an object of class `PKAnimation`, even though it simply inherits `CABasicAnimation`'s method. Now, overriding it, and then calling the `super` implementation, should work no differently than not overriding it -- in both cases, it gets a `PKAnimation` object.